# use permalink instead of slug in friendly-id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, migration, friendly-id

I am new to friendly-id and i have this in my post.rb model

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

and friendly_id generator migration is

```
def change
  create_table :friendly_id_slugs do |t|
    t.string   :slug,           :null => false
    t.integer  :sluggable_id,   :null => false
    t.string   :sluggable_type, :limit => 50
    t.string   :scope
    t.datetime :created_at
  end
  add_index :friendly_id_slugs, :sluggable_id
  add_index :friendly_id_slugs, [:slug, :sluggable_type]
  add_index :friendly_id_slugs, [:slug, :sluggable_type, :scope], :unique => true
  add_index :friendly_id_slugs, :sluggable_type
end
```

and i added slug attribute with this migration

```
def change
  add_column :posts, :slug, :string
  add_index :posts, :slug
  Post.find_each(&:save)
end
```

but I want use permalink instead of slug field like post.permalink
what i really need to change?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the name slug, either, it sounds like a naked snail.. The :slug_column option should work. If you do not want to use the default "slug" column then you can define it as follows:

```
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged, slug_column: :permalink

def change
  add_column :posts, :permalink, :string
  add_index :posts, :permalink
end
```